# Will the runtime for this algorithm be O(nlogn)?

Tags: python-3.x, runtime, big-o

```
for index in range(len(my_list) - 1): 
     if (index != 0):
    
        if my_list[index - 1] > my_list[index + 1]:
            if (my_list[index - 1] > my_list[index]):
                newList.append(my_list[index - 1])
        else:
            if (my_list[index + 1] > my_list[index]):
                newList.append(my_list[index + 1])
    else :
        if (my_list[index + 1] > my_list[index]):
            newList.append(my_list[index + 1])
newList = list(set(newList))
```

I'm trying to return the heighest neighbours for each element in list such that the neighbour is higher than the main element.
eg: List = [[3,7,1,4,2,5,6]
The result is:- [5, 6, 7]
I just wanted to confirm wether my runtime is O(nLogn)

Comment: You have only one loop with the linear running time (O(n)) and no recursion. Conversion to a set and back to a list is also O(n). The code fragment runs in O(n).

Comment: Why do you want your code to run in O(n log n)? You do realize that O(n log n) is slower than O(n) right?

Comment: Yes I do know, but I was required to code this in O(nlogn) time

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you essentially loop over your list from `index=0` to `index=len(my_list) - 1`, without ever doing recursion or without ever looping over your list within the first outer loop. (you have no inner loops, in other words)

This means your code will always run in O(n) time.

Comment: How can I make it O(nlogn). Probably add a while loop? Is there a better way to attain the result like make the use of Divide and Conquer algorithm?

Comment: @Rupin Mehra It would be challenging to artificially make this algorithm run in O(n log n) due to it's very simple and also very precise nature of local features. That warrants a separate question.